# React events not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While working with `<img>` tags and getting familiar with React, I found that my `onLoad` and `onError` events weren't firing. After simplifying my usage to even the most basic React component, I'm still finding that events aren't firing.

In the following component, I'd expect that clicking the rendered `<div>` to log to the console. It renders fine, but upon clicking it, nothing happens. Am I missing something?

I'm using React 0.12.2 under Chrome 40.0.2214.111 on OS X 10.10.2, with code packed by webpack 1.5.3 and jsx-loader 0.12.2.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

module.exports = (function () {
  'use strict';
  var React = require('react');
  var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'SomeComponent',
    doSomething: function (e) {
      console.log('did something');
    },
    render: function () {
      return (
        /* jshint ignore:start */
        <div onClick={this.doSomething}>Do Something</div>
        /* jshint ignore:end */
      );
    }
  });
  return SomeComponent;
})();
```

Comment: Your code works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/9840/ - there is probably something you're missing when you a) import the component or b) render the component.

Comment: Wow, you're right! If I copy the contents of my component and replace my `var SomeComponent = require('./some-component.jsx');` call with the entirety, it logs as expected. I've yet to figure out why when using CommonJS it would render OK, but not fire events.

Comment: Try this `module.exports = SomeComponent`, itll fix it for you.

Comment: Hmm, I switched to that style: `var SomeComponent = React.createClass({ ... }); module.exports = SomeComponent;` and it renders, but still no events fire.

Comment: Posted my setup here for inspection: https://github.com/commandtab/react-some-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

In `example.jsx`, I realized I wasn't `require()`ing React before using it:

```
var React = require('react');
var SomeComponent = require('./some-component.jsx');
React.render( ... );
```

It seems so obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that in my JSX file _that made use of the component_ I was missing the React `require()`. At the time, I thought the issue was with my component, not the setup, but that was not the case. The applied fix can be seen here: https://github.com/commandtab/react-some-component/blob/master/example.jsx#L3 I appreciate your help, though!